# Python 3.5.x multiprocessing throwing "OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory" on a 74% free RAM system

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, ubuntu, multiprocessing, psycopg

I wrote a Python 3.5 application that spawns several processes using `multiprocessing` library. It runs on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on a dedicated server machine that ships with 2 x Intel Xeon E2690 v1 (8 cores each) and 96GB of RAM.

This system runs a PostgreSQL instance which is configured to use a maximum of about 32GB of RAM (`effective_cache_size` is set to `32GB`), but that's only a reminder for the purposes of my question (I tried several combinations of `effective_cache_size`, `work_mem`, `shared_buffers`, etc.).

Each process opens a connection to the database and reuses it many times.

Here's a simplified portion of code that shows how i spawn a new process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

process = Process(target=start_algorithm, args=(arg1, arg2))
process.start()

def start_algorithm():
    while True :
        time.sleep(1)
    return True
```

After spawning more than 200 processes (the exact number isn't always the same), the application throws an exception when trying to spawn a new process:

```
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

`ulimit -a` output is:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 384500
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 524288
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 384500
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

In `/etc/sysctl.conf` I set the following parameters which work well for `mdadm` and PostgreSQL:

```
# Allows for 84GB shared_buffers in PostgreSQL
kernel.shmmax = 90914313216
kernel.shmall = 22020096

# Various PostgreSQL optimizations
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 90
vm.swappiness = 4
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0
vm.dirty_ratio = 15
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 3

# mdadm optimizations
vm.min_free_kbytes=262144
kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns = 5000000
kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled = 0
dev.raid.speed_limit_max=1000000
dev.raid.speed_limit_min=1000000
```

I tried also to set and unset `vm.nr_hugepages` but it didn't get rid of the problem.

Before  starting my Python application, the RAM usage is about `500 MB` over `96 GB`, so I can see that the overall RAM is quite empty. After spawning those 200+ processes, the RAM starts to fill and it reaches a maximum at about `20 GB` (the remanining `74 GB` are still free) and then it throws the `Cannot allocate memory` exception.

The question is: **why?**

I tried to measure the footprint of the overall processes and found [`memory_profiler`](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler), a library/tool for Python. I was able to get this graph:

[image: Memory footprint of 287 processes.]

If I'm not wrong, those are about `47500 MiB` of memory, so about `50 GB` of "occupied" RAM. Each process footprintf should be about `170 MB`. The problem is that I'm not able to see that amount of occupied RAM *anywhere*. Here are some outputs:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            94G         18G         74G        570M        1,6G         73G
Swap:           15G          0B         15G

$ vmstat -S M
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0  75879     81   1518    0    0     3    40  229  157 12  1 86  0  0

$ top
Tasks: 1457 total,   2 running, 1455 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3,1 us,  0,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 95,8 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,2 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem : 98847552 total, 77698752 free, 19509612 used,  1639188 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 15825916 total, 15825916 free,        0 used. 77580104 avail Mem
```

I was able to start 287 processes by lowering the amount of memory required by PostgreSQL, but this leads always to A LOT of free RAM (`74GB`). Here's my configuration file for PostgreSQL 9.6 (`postgresql.conf`):

```
max_connections=2000
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1,192.168.2.90'
shared_buffers = 1GB
work_mem = 42MB
port=5433
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
effective_cache_size = 32GB
default_statistics_target = 1000
random_page_cost=1.2
seq_page_cost=1.0
max_files_per_process = 500 # default 1000
huge_pages = off
```

### EDIT

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40173829/2757210) answer on SO and found a way to isntantly measure the overall memory usage.

Python (288 processes spawned):

```
$ ps aux | grep python3 | awk '{sum=sum+$6}; END {print sum/1024 " MB"}'
53488.1 MB
```

PostgreSQL:

```
$ ps aux | grep postgres | awk '{sum=sum+$6}; END {print sum/1024 " MB"}'
20653.4 MB
```

I still don't understand why the usual tools (`vmstat`, `free`, `top`, `glances`) shows another amount of used RAM.

Comment: did you try to start the processes not using fork (the default), but using spawn, as described here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42587951/119861

Comment: @hansaplast I edited my question and added the code I use to spawn a new process. I use the Process.start() method and don't use any pool. If I use the `spawn` or `forkserver` methods using `set_start_method()` I get a sort of `can't pickle` error. The class from which I fork the new process is loaded dinamically. Probably you are right that it's the way to go, but I wonder if does exist another solution.