# OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory when using python multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I am trying to apply a function to 5 cross validation sets in parallel using Python's `multiprocessing` and repeat that for different parameter values, like so:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

#simulated datasets
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(3348,868), dtype='int8'))
y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(2, size=3348, dtype='int64'))

#dummy function to apply
def _work(args):
    del(args)

for C in np.arange(0.0,2.0e-3,1.0e-6):
    splitter = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
    with mp.Pool(processes=5) as pool:
        pool_results = \
            pool.map(
                func=_work,
                iterable=((C,X.iloc[train_index],X.iloc[test_index]) for train_index, test_index in splitter.split(X, y))
            )
```

However halfway through execution I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mre.py", line 19, in <module>
    with mp.Pool(processes=5) as pool:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/context.py", line 118, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 168, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 233, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/context.py", line 267, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 20, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 67, in _launch
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I'm running this on Ubuntu 16.04 with 32Gb of memory, and checking `htop` during execution it never goes over 18.5Gb, so I don't think I'm running out of memory.
It is definitly due to the splitting of my dataframes with the indexes from `splitter.split(X,y)` since when I directly pass my dataframes to the `Pool` object no error is thrown.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45620524/8650928) that says it might be due to too many file dependencies being created, but I have no idea how I might go about fixing that, and isn't the context manager supposed to help avoid this sort of problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`os.fork()` makes a copy of a process, so if you're sitting at about 18 GB of usage, and want to call `fork`, you need another 18 GB.  Twice 18 is 36 GB, which is well over 32 GB.  While this analysis is (intentionally) naive—some things don't get copied on fork—it's probably sufficient to explain the problem.

The solution is either to make the pools earlier, when less memory needs to be copied, or to work harder at sharing the largest objects.  Or, of course, add more memory (perhaps just virtual memory, i.e., swap space) to the system.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that at first, but the thing is this error is thrown after after about 1000 processes are executed, and the memory usage keeps going steadily up during this execution. Could the processes not be freeing their memory once they're done? Or do they have to wait until all the processes are executed?

Comment: The one that's doing the fork is growing, probably. That, or the others are still holding resources (without a full diagnostic of the system it's hard to know precisely what's going on). In any case `os.fork` is asking for more RAM and the OS is saying "there's not enough left".