# How do I install dependecies in azure jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, ml-studio

Trying to install 'calmap' dependency using the azure dependency management syntax

```
!pip install calmap
```

and getting

```
ExceptionPexpect: pty.fork() failed: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

whenever I use anything with `!`, on its own or with arguments, I get the above error

It also worked the first time I used it yesterday, but no more

Comment: seems to be memory related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364064/oserror-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory-when-using-python-multiprocessing-poo

Comment: Any idea why this might be happening on azure in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue related to the notebook itself. Fixed by creating a new notebook